# How to unit test HttpClient retry logic using junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito, apache-httpclient-4.x, powermock

I am working on apache http client to consume services and I have a requirement to retry the requests based on timeout and based on response code.
For this I have implemented the code as below. How can I write the junit tests for retry logic for both timeout and response code scenarios. I would like to write a unit test in such a way that when I send any post/get request if it returns 429 error code response or any TimeOutException I should make sure retry logic is executed properly. I did not get an idea on how to write unit test for retry logic.
By googling I found the below link but it doesn't helpful to me.

[Unit testing DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39579202/unit-testing-defaulthttprequestretryhandler)

I am using junit,Mockito to write unit tests and PowerMock to mock static methods.

```
public class GetClient {

private static CloseableHttpClient httpclient;

public static CloseableHttpClient getInstance() {

        try {
            HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClients.custom().setMaxConnTotal(3)
                    .setMaxConnPerRoute(3);
            builder.setRetryHandler(retryHandler());
            builder.setServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(new ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy() {
            int waitPeriod = 200;

            @Override
            public boolean retryRequest(final HttpResponse response, final int executionCount,
                final HttpContext context) {

                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                return (((statusCode == 429) || (statusCode >= 300 && statusCode <= 399))
                            && (executionCount < 3));
            }

            @Override
            public long getRetryInterval() {
                return waitPeriod;
            }
            });            

            httpclient = builder.build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //handle exception
        }
        return httpclient;
    }

     private static HttpRequestRetryHandler retryHandler() {
        return (exception, executionCount, context) -> {
            if (executionCount > maxRetries) {
                // Do not retry if over max retry count
                return false;
            }
            if (exception instanceof InterruptedIOException) {                
                // Timeout
                return true;
            }
            if (exception instanceof UnknownHostException) {
                // Unknown host
                return false;
            }
            if (exception instanceof ConnectTimeoutException) {
                // Connection refused
                return false;
            }
            if (exception instanceof SSLException) {
                // SSL handshake exception
                return false;
            }
            HttpClientContext clientContext = HttpClientContext.adapt(context);
            HttpRequest request = clientContext.getRequest();
            boolean idempotent = !(request instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequest);
            if (idempotent) {
                // Retry if the request is considered idempotent
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };
    }
}

public CloseableHttpResponse uploadFile(){    
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = GetClient.getInstance();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(post);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //handle exception
        }
        return response;    
   }
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: How did you write unit tests for this class? Do you have any tests that call `uploadFile` that are successful?

Comment: I would also be interested to see a simple running test for `uploadFile()` . First of all the structure here, calling static items a lot, is hostile to writing unit tests, and PowerMock is not my friend (except for WhiteBox). My overall strategy is to build the httpclient as a mock, throw an exception for the proper method (e.g. using `Mockito.when(...).thenThrow(...).thenReturn(...)` ) and for the mock to use `Mockito.doCallRealMethod()` for the  proper method. But all in all, not seeing a working version for the `uploadFile` Method this is just a guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your httpClient has a "target" url, lets say localhost:1234. What you want to test is your retry code so you shouldn't touch the httpClient itself ( as it is not your component you shouldn't need to test it also. )

So the problem in hand is when your localhost:1234 response is problematic you want to see that the retry logic that WILL run ( not your implementation.. if it doesn't run with correct conf its their problem ) works.. The only thing you have to do is mock the "localhost:1234" !

This tool http://wiremock.org/ is the perfect choice to do this. You can create stub for your target url and give series of responses depending on almost anything you like.

Your code should look like 
before calling `uploadFile`

```java
    stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/hash"))
        .willReturn(aResponse()
            .withStatus(200)
            .withBody(externalResponse)));
```

and 
after calling `uploadFile`

and verify steps to verify your mock requests that reached your mock endpoint

```java
    Assert.assert* //... whatever you want to assert in your handlers / code / resposnes
    verify(postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/hash")));
```

Comment: Thank for your reply Michael. If possible could you please provide me with clear example for my scenario. I am completely new to wiremock, do not have knowledge on it to write unit test for my scenario.

Comment: This guide is one of my favorites on wiremock https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-wiremock. Have a look and let me know if you are ok with this. 
For multiple responses just repeat the `willReturn` method on the stub. It will work in the same way as junit. Each time the stub is called it will provide the next in line willReturn

Comment: The URL what we are using in urlEqualTo() should be same as the url which we use in production ?  If suppose my real time code url is https://abc.xyz.com/fetch/token with request body parameters then can I specify any mock url in test method like urlEqualTo("https://test.com") ?

Comment: your wiremock server will run in something like localhost:9999. This is omitted in urlEqualsTo() and needs to be provided to your code with some configuration ( as a url shouldn't be hardcoded it should already be implemented to inject the configuration ) the trailing url /fetch/token which is propably hardcoded as it is core path of your project can be used as is. so urlEqualsTo("/fetch/token"). You should use absolute paths in tests and define everything to reduce pointless/wrong tests. So Start wiremock. stub with urlEqualsTo("/fetch/token") add 2-3 willReturn run your test and then verify!

Comment: I have implemented the test cases and running as expected. When I run the whole build using maven I am not able to see the code coverage for these test cases. I am using jacoco maven plugin to get the code coverage report. Does this plugin will not support coverage for wire mock ? Or I have written these tests in inner class which is static. Because of this it is not showing the coverage ?

Comment: JaCoCo should not care about your test frameworks ( wiremock and stuff ) as it enchances your actual code to create the coverage.. I haven't used configured JaCoCo for a quite some time so I cannot really answer your question. A blind guess of what the problem could be is the class you implement for your retry logic. This will be executed by the httpClient and not you. So the JaCoCo may be unable to enhance it for monitoring. Again thats a wild guess!

Comment: Seems the problem is innerclass tests are not getting picked when outer class is running.

Comment: Useful to know. Thank you.